# Scan QR android app

Tags: android

I am having trouble with creating a QR reading app, it can read this one:[image]

but I cannot read the following:

[image]

Now some code:

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'


public void qrOperations(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "qrOperations has been called");
    new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan();
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");
    integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
    integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
    integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (scanResult != null) {

        // handle scan result
        contantsString =  scanResult.getContents()==null?"0":scanResult.getContents();
        Log.d(TAG,"scanResult.getContents():" +scanResult.getContents());

        if (!contantsString.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "LOOKS GREAT!!!" + contantsString);
            Toast.makeText(this, "LOOKS GREAT!!!\n" + contantsString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        Log.d(TAG, "result: " + contantsString);


    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Problem to secan the barcode.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The funny thing is when I try debugging in the "Toast" I do get the results but not in the "Log" ???

Comment: Which data you get in the `Toast`?

Comment: Thank you for asking @Mr Neo!  The QR code info that is supposed to go on into the contantsString variable but for some unknown reason is not !

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint and run with the debugger attached to see what the value of `contantsString` is at that point?

Comment: btw, did you use two different services to generate them? they look slightly different (in their structure)

Comment: take a look at this https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx It can read both

Comment: @Shmuel Thank you for the link! I did try to use a breakpoints as you advised but I was unable to understand what is actually happening (the way I see it when the app "gets it" the code is really running twice and when it does not it is only running once).